# How to copy all Row from table to same other

Tags: mysql

I tried this to copy

```
INSERT INTO order_report (qty,pro_id,pro_name,price)
SELECT NULL  qty,pro_id,pro_name,price
FROM sale_details
```

But it only copies one value from the other table. I want to copy all rows to another table one Time!

Comment: use this approach:                                                                                                        `INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, City, Country FROM Suppliers;`

Comment: i think it's same ! only without null & i have tried it

Comment: why you are using null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems wrong. You have 4 columns for insert and 5 columns in select. You need the same number of columns (and matching types) between the two clauses.

Try without the NULL in select

```
INSERT INTO order_report (qty,pro_id,pro_name,price)
SELECT   qty,pro_id,pro_name,price
FROM sale_details
```

Comment: this problem happend when , i have  two row in sale_details to copy to order_report
if i have 1 row in sale_details Query working  ..! 
problem : i can't submit two rows or more !

Comment: can you show error message?

Comment: nor error show but !

Comment: @WaledK.Fikrey  your comment is not clear ..  you have not error and the insert query don't produce .. any  result  ..  ???  ..  seems strange to me ..  try execute the same query in a SQL console  and see whot happen .. anyway  .. your first query was wrong ..  be sure you are using a valid query  ..  could be you have not an error because you don't read the error message ..  for this be sure you manage properly the error message in your php code

Comment: i fixed my query but it's only copy one row from table ! 
when table have 1 row --> coping successful 
when have two 2 row -- >  coping falied ---> no result

Comment: ..  I'm not in your data .. so you should update your question adding   a proper data sample and the expected  result   your anctual result and the code you are really using